# Reactjs setEmail is not a function onChange although it is function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-props

It gives an error i do not know why, If you look my codes, there is not any problem you will see.
Login Route page:

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    
    <LoginPage
              email={email}
              setEmail={setEmail} />
```

Login Form codes:

```
    const {
        email,
        setEmail,
      } = props;
    
    <input
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  />
```

Comment: Try setting it locally in the same component using const [email, setEmail] = useState(''), if that works then at least you know it's the parent causing the issue.

Comment: what do you mean? I need to carry this props, because there are lots of props like username password etc. I just asked for 1 props, but also the others have the same problem

Comment: Your code is not compilable.

Comment: so what should i do @xehpuk

Comment: @efesahin Post a complete example.

Comment: I  do not understand :/

Comment: so in your Login Form component simply set const [email, setEmail] = useState("") and comment out your line of code and see if the onChange works then?

Comment: Please add more of your code. It is hard to tell which component is which and there maybe other errors which we cannot debug like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login Page Component
`<LoginPage />`

Login Form Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="email"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      {/* Other components */}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: why? Shouldn't loginpage component has props?

Comment: Of course, we are just testing the child component in this instance similar to a unit test. Just give it a go and see if you get expected results then we can look at the parent component.